# Rewrite permalink for specific posts

Tags: url-rewriting

A client wants certain posts to have a custom permalink structure. Client is running WordPress 2.8.5 and upgrade is not currently an option, so I can't use a custom post type. That being the case, it seems I must use a category to create the custom structure.

So, I need the site-wide structure `http://example.com/%post_id%/%postname%/` to turn into `http://example.com/%postname%/` just for posts in the one category.

I gather that I need to use `add_rewrite_rule` to change the permalink. But I'm having trouble changing the URL structure at all adding rules to `functions.php`, and I don't understand regex well.  Can I filter for a generic structure such as `%post_id%`, or only strings?  Can anyone provide some guidance as to how I may accomplish this goal?

Comment: Why is upgrading not an option?

Comment: a couple of things- adding a rewrite rule only handles the incoming requests, you also need to filter `post_link` to generate the proper permalinks for these posts. that said, I think you're going to have some issues trying to achieve this structure, if you add a rewrite rule to catch `/%postname%/`, you'll also intercept the page post type. can you not just use pages for these instead of posts?

Comment: Client is scared of upgrading hassles and associated downtime.   I suggested an upgrade and custom post type..   they just want to 'keep this project simple' and do an upgrade later.  Tl;dr, its their decision.

Comment: I was thinking of logic something like, if category is x then rewrite permalink to remove postID.   Possible?

Comment: I don't think pages will work.   These posts are supposed to behave like regular posts, except with a different template and permalink.

Comment: The rewrite API and everything related has been changed during the last four years. Force your client to update. Test everything on a local copy of the site before.